# How i can create a Qt interface for a Java App?

Tags: java, windows, qt, user-interface, focus

I have a Java app on Windows, but I don't know it.
It's necessary sometimes insert some scripts to use it (and they are a lot).
I want to automate that with a Qt app that passes this scripts directly at 
lineEdit in this Java App.
How i can do ? In particular it's find a way to have focus with this lineEdit.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give more specifics? What sort of scripts? What does "lineEdit" mean?

Comment: Yes sure. In this app (it's a game) there 2 ways to play: normal and test mode. With normal all is automatized. With test mode it's possible to modify game with some scripts inserted in chat through that line edit. I'd like to insert these scripts with a qt app. A way could be copy and past, but i don't know how to have focus in that place

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to you learn Java SE. I thing it's the best alternative.
read the docs: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/index.html